# Overpass query. Absence of [maxsize] returns significantly smaller results

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have two overpass queries.

```
node(33.68336,-117.89466,34.14946,-117.03498);
way["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link|primary|primary_link|secondary|secondary_link|tertiary|tertiary_link|road|residential|service"](bn);
(._;>;);
out;
```

The query above returns an osm.xml file that is 167.306 kb big.

```
[out:xml][maxsize:2000000000];
(
    node(33.68336,-117.89466,34.14946,-117.03498);
    way["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link|primary|primary_link|secondary|seconda ry_link|tertiary|tertiary_link|road|residential|service"](bn);
    (._;>;);
);
out;
```

The second query returns a file that is 618.994 kb big. Why does the second query return a significantly bigger result? Does the first query not give me the full dataset? Is there a way to get the same result with both queries? (The absence of [maxsize] sometimes leads to an error…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that there is something missing about your query:

`node(33.68336,-117.89466,34.14946,-117.03498);` should return **all** the nodes in this area,which is a lot of data.

[image: box]

then the second line:

`way"highway"~“motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link|primary|primary_link|secondary|secondary_link|tertiary|tertiary_link|road|residential|service”;`

gives an error, as it should be written with brackets and straight quotes as so:

`way["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link|primary|primary_link|secondary|secondary_link|tertiary|tertiary_link|road|residential|service"];`
but this looks for **all** the roads in the world, and your first query is not used any more, as your output is only the second query. But that is a huge amount of data, probably in the GB range.

So I don't see how you would get only 167 kB. I assume you must a bounding box or some other filter that you did not mention.

But in your second example, you make an union of the two queries, as you put them in brackets:
`(... ; ...;); out;` so you would get all the nodes in the area *and* all the roads in the world. And again, if you have an extra bounding box or filter, you might get only 619 kB. Supposing that there are a lot of non-road nodes, it makes sense that you get more data, as you get the union of the two searches (all nodes + nodes from the roads)

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the second line of the query. I edited my question. The response is 167 mb big (this is german number formatting). But what I didn't know is that the brackets lead to a union. This explains why I got significantly more data with my second query. This solves my issue. Thank you!